# Unit testing vuejs methods using Jest

Tags: javascript, vue.js, unit-testing, jestjs

I'm trying to test the methods in jest framework. For javascript methods i was able to import the methods from file using require() function and test it (expect(addition(1,2).toBe(3))).
But unable to replicate the same in VueJS methods.

```
  // VueJS
  export default defineComponent({
  name: "App",
  components: {
    HelloWorld,
  },
  methods: {
    addition(a: number, b: number) {
      return a + b;
    },
    subtraction(a: number, b: number) {
      return a - b;
    },
    multiplication(a: number, b: number) {
      return a * b;
    },
  },
});
```

test file

```
import addition from "./App.vue"
describe("HelloWorld.vue", () => {
  it("testing vue method", () => {
    expect(addition(1,2).toBe(3));
  });
});

//error on line 4 states "Value of type 'DefineComponent<{}, {}, any, ComputedOptions, MethodOptions, ComponentOptionsMixin, 
// ComponentOptionsMixin, ... 4 more ..., {}>' is not callable. Did you mean to include 'new'?"
```

Comment: Check out https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/guides/#knowing-what-to-test - my two cents...for the added difficulty of diagnosing failing tests in a VDOM I'd rather just run browser tests. Maybe I'm just missing the mark with Jest though.

Comment: Yes! I was referring to do unit testing using JEST framework.

Comment: The test fails because default import is component definition object, while you expect it to be `addition` function for some reason. It's the same with vanilla JS tests when imports go wrong. Could be `expect(comp.options.methods.addition.call(mockInstance, 1, 2))...`. But it's correct to test a component with Vue utils as said. A test with Jest alone doesn't have much value because you test not original behaviour but something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `App.vue` file is compiled into a component definition, which is used to instantiate the `App` component with Vue Test Util's [`mount`](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/#mount) or [`shallowMount`](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/#shallowmount), which results in a test wrapper. The wrapper has a [`vm` property](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/wrapper/#properties) that provides direct access to the component's methods and props.

So your test should look similar to this:

```js
import { shallowMount } from "@vue/test-utils";
import App from "./App.vue";

describe("App.vue", () => {
  it("testing vue method", () => {
    const wrapper = shallowMount(App);
    expect(wrapper.vm.addition(1,2)).toBe(3);
  });
});
```